# Обработка большого количества изображений

Tags: ajax, php, изображения

Всем доброго дня.

Ребята, возник вопрос касательно обработки большого количества изображений. Скрипт хранит оригиналы всех картинок в отдельной директории. Файлов там порядка 10к. Я понимаю, что это не особо много. Но при перенарезке их копий все зависает (`504 Gateway Time-out`).

Ежу понятно, что нужно обрабатывать не все сразу, а частями. Отсюда возник вопрос. Как лучше это организовать?

Получить в массив все изображения и уже брать от туда частями и обрабатывать? Может есть какие-то готовые AJAX решения, чтобы не писать все с нуля?

Буду благодарен за помощь и советы.

Comment: 10000 файлов в одном каталоге? это много. Я бы разбил хотя бы по 500-700 на каталог.

Вы пытаетесь все эти файлы одновременно обработать? Это значит, что один файл должен быть обработан быстрее, чем за 30/10000 = 3 мс, что скорее всего не так и поэтому и получаете timeout.

Перенарезку копий лучше запускать отдельно, например, с консоли. Тогда не будет таймаута.

Comment: как вариант - gearman+supervsord в job gearaman'a - задача обработки одного изображения, ваш скрипт присылает данные о картинке и нужное количество воркеров их потихоньку обрабатывает. 

Второй вариант - просто сложить пути всех необработанных в базу данных, как ключ, скрипт обработки запускается скажем кроном и обрабатывает по 100, обработанные помечает, запускаем раз в две  минуты (можно ещё флаг в базе сделать, чтобы вторая копия не запускалась, или как-то по-другому разрешить возможный конфликт)

Comment: «Быстро и грязно» решить проблему таймаута – запускать php скрипт не через веб-сервер, а из командной строки, как и посоветовал @KoVadim.

Comment: @KoVadim, ну я сразу подумал, что сайт упадет, так и вышло. На 5к нормально проходит, думал может потянет)
Разбивать не вариант. Не мало переписывать, да и движок регулярно обновляемый.

@eicto, @KoVadim проблема в том, что администратор сайта не сможет лазить в консоль\на сервер, чтобы производить нужные манипуляции. Ему нужна просто кнопка. Друг мой не разбирается совсем во всем этом.

Я по этому и думал обрабатывать частями используя AJAX. Но никогда такого не делал до этого, "подводных камней" не знаю.

Comment: @drop_off, это можно делать по крону. а в решении с gearman по событию добавления новых картинок. Если ваш друг не может администрировать собственный сервер, вы наверное сможете ему помочь.

Comment: Перенарезка задача не частая. Только если добавляется новый формат изображений, либо под дизайн нужно.

Сделал сейчас так

весь массив оригинальных изображений разбивается на ровные части и сохраняется построчно по txt файлам.
Далее, каждый файл обрабатывается с определенной паузой.

А если по крону делать, сервер так же не упадет при обработке?